# Remove object from list by identity

Tags: c++

In the following example a std::list stores objects of type Resource (by value, not pointing to). The Resource class does not provide a less than comparison nor equality operator. What is a good way to remove an object by identity (aka memory address). Can i avoid O(n) somehow? Is std::list the right container?

```
// Definition of the container
std::list<Resource> resources;

// Code
Resource *closedResource = resourceFromList();
for (std::list<Resource>::iterator it = resources.begin(); it != resources.end(); ++it)
{
    if (closedResource == &*it)
    {
        resources.erase(it);
        break;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Assume that the Resource class implements move semantic. Furthermore the Resource reregisters itself for any "movement" by a kind of Selector (cp. epoll or java.nio.Selector) for event notifications.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use a `std::list` instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: How can you avoid O(n) with a list? However you traverse a list, there could always be an arrangement in which you discover the element you're looking for only after looking at every other element. If quick lookup/erase by value is important, you might like to use a different container.

Comment: Does it make sense for a Resource to be copyable?

Comment: @Emilie: Good point -- given that the OP is already using `Resource` in an STL container, I think we can assume that it fulfills the requirements for being used in a container?

Comment: @mazatwork: I don't think it's possible for `Resource` to have value semantics, while supporting the concept of identity at the same time. It's like saying you want to delete the integer `3` by it's address. Unless... if `Resource` has some kind `id` member.

Comment: You must be identifying your Resources _somehow_.  However that is (name? unique id?), you should be able to use it with a map or unordered_map to allow fast insertion/removal.  (My personal theory is that `list` is never the right data structure for any purpose.  I might be exaggerating.)

Comment: I prefer std::list over std::vector because there might be arbitrary erasure. Assume the Resource class implements move constructor and move assignment.

Comment: @mazatwork: Does Resource already provide something that identifies it from others (like an OS handle)? Are you able to add an "id" member? Are you open to using Boost for a solution?

Comment: @Nemo: iterator invalidation semantics is one reason to use a list above other containers.  A nice way to implement a `unordered_list` is to build a vector of iterators that point into a list which, in turn, stores the objects.

Answer (score 2):

You're storing `Resource` copies in the container, so later finding an element by address doesn't make much sense.
What you can do is save `list::iterator`s since `list` has the property that iterators are not invalidated by any operation expect explicitly erasing that iterator (or clearing the entire `list`).

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* Sorry, never mind this answer -- if you are certain only to be removing at most one element, then your loop is fine.

---

Never mind whether comparing by memory address is sensible, but to use `list::erase` in a loop you have to write it a little differently to avoid incrementing an invalidated iterator:

```
for (std::list<Resource>::iterator it = resources.begin(); it != resources.end(); )
{
  if (want_to_erase)   it = resources.erase(it); // advances to the next position
  else                 ++it;
}
```

If you have no other requirements than look-up by address, you could always just make a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` of elements and implement `Resource::operator<()` as pointer comparison.

Either way, there are certain conditions on types for them to be eligible as STL container members; as was asked in the comments, do those conditions apply to your `Resource` class? Otherwise you could just make a container of `std::shared_ptr<Resource>` and use its inbuilt comparators, and for example make an `std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Resource>>`.

Comment: I think the erase is quite safe since i break and do not rely on the iterator any longer.

Comment: @mazatwork: Yes, I just spotted that; never mind this answer!

Comment: But the second part of your initial post might be the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

"Is std::list the right container?"

I doubt it. If this class does not provide a comparison operator you can still provide one yourself

```
struct resourcecomparation {
  const bool operator() (const Resource &l, const Resource &r) const;
}resourcecomparator;
```

and then you can use, for instance, an `std::set<resource, resourcecomparator>`.

Comment: While you're at it, you might just make the comparator a member function, since that doesn't seem to conflict with anything going by the OP's description.